# making layout for iphone 4 & 5, stuck with dpi

Tags: iphone, css, layout

I have .psd from my designer with 640px width of the layout. As i understand, i should use 0.5 of used dpi to see the real sizes of elements. But it's not right, the real size of fonts, images is less then 0.5.

I used:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
#logo { 
    background: url("/rev/rev2/img/logokp2x.png") 0px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But it's bad, because image is too big on retina display.

How can i understand what is the real size of elements should i do?

Regards

Comment: use height and width property for #logo. Or you can modify the background-size property value.

Comment: The problem is not how to get real size. The problem is how to understand what size do i need. I have image 640*960, so i can't understand what font size should i use, or what image size should i use.